# How can you change Network settings (IP Address, DNS, WINS, Host Name) with code in C#

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, networking

I am developing a wizard for a machine that is to be used as a backup of other machines.  When it replaces an existing machine, it needs to set its IP address, DNS, WINS, and host name to match the machine being replaced.

Is there a library in .net (C#) which allows me to do this programatically?

There are multiple NICs, each which need to be set individually.

**EDIT**

Thank you [TimothyP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code-in-c#209822) for your example.  It got me moving on the right track and the quick reply was awesome.

Thanks [balexandre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code-in-c#209983).  Your code is perfect.  I was in a rush and had already adapted the example TimothyP linked to, but I would have loved to have had your code sooner.

I've also developed a routine using similar techniques for changing the computer name.  I'll post it in the future so subscribe to this questions [RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/209779) if you want to be informed of the update.  I may get it up later today or on Monday after a bit of cleanup.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me sending you to an example,
but this is really a perfect example:
[http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/oazswitchnetconfig.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/oazswitchnetconfig.aspx)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Just made this in a few minutes:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication_CS
{
  class NetworkManagement
  {
    public void setIP(string ip_address, string subnet_mask)
    {
      ManagementClass objMC =
        new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
      ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

      foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
      {
        if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
        {
          ManagementBaseObject setIP;
          ManagementBaseObject newIP =
            objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");

          newIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { ip_address };
          newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { subnet_mask };

          setIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);
        }
      }
    }

    public void setGateway(string gateway)
    {
      ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
      ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

      foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
      {
        if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
        {
          ManagementBaseObject setGateway;
          ManagementBaseObject newGateway =
            objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");

          newGateway["DefaultIPGateway"] = new string[] { gateway };
          newGateway["GatewayCostMetric"] = new int[] { 1 };

          setGateway = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", newGateway, null);
        }
      }
    }

    public void setDNS(string NIC, string DNS)
    {
      ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
      ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

      foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
      {
        if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
        {
          // if you are using the System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface
          // you'll need to change this line to
          // if (objMO["Caption"].ToString().Contains(NIC))
          // and pass in the Description property instead of the name 
          if (objMO["Caption"].Equals(NIC))
          {
            ManagementBaseObject newDNS =
              objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
            newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = DNS.Split(',');
            ManagementBaseObject setDNS =
              objMO.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDNS, null);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    public void setWINS(string NIC, string priWINS, string secWINS)
    {
      ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
      ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

      foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
      {
        if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
        {
          if (objMO["Caption"].Equals(NIC))
          {
            ManagementBaseObject setWINS;
            ManagementBaseObject wins =
            objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetWINSServer");
            wins.SetPropertyValue("WINSPrimaryServer", priWINS);
            wins.SetPropertyValue("WINSSecondaryServer", secWINS);

            setWINS = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetWINSServer", wins, null);
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: just like EnableStatic, is there any way to programatically switch the IP back to dynamic? EnableDynamic? I want to build a tool to toggle between a static and dynamic IP with one click. Thanks.

Comment: For those interested, you can find a list of all the properties and methods on this ManagementObject here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217.aspx

Comment: @balexandre how can we make workable under limited user account?

Comment: its working fine for me but i can't understand why and how you are getting a return value? i can't see any return type of InvokeMethod

Comment: @aalaap you can use [`EnableDHCP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390378.aspx)

Comment: @Eric I do not belive you can, as you will require admin privileges for that.

Comment: In case someone else is wondering, to reset the DNS servers to "Automatic" just set the DNSSearverSearchOrder to null. e.g. newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = null;

Comment: Note: you must add a reference to System.Management to your project.

Comment: If you get "BadImageFormatException" "Cannot load a reference assembly for execution" it means that you need to set your project (under configuration manager) to run as x86.

In my case I am writing a NetCore console app and needed to make this change.

Comment: nicely caught @D.Squire but then again, when I wrote the answer there was no .NET Core :) ... it's been a while, ehehe

Comment: It's better to check the return value of the `InvokeMethod` method call. For example, for `setIP`, use `setIP["ReturnValue"]` to get the return value.

Comment: but how to reset ID? need to change to a new valid IP (automatic) when blocked.

Answer (score 32):

Refactored the code from balexandre a little so objects gets disposed and the new language features of C# 3.5+ are used (Linq, var, etc). Also renamed the variables to more meaningful names. I also merged some of the functions to be able to do more configuration with less WMI interaction. I removed the WINS code as I don't need to configure WINS anymore. Feel free to add the WINS code if you need it.

For the case anybody likes to use the refactored/modernized code I put it back into the community here.

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper class to set networking configuration like IP address, DNS servers, etc.
/// </summary>
public class NetworkConfigurator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Set's a new IP Address and it's Submask of the local machine
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ipAddress">The IP Address</param>
    /// <param name="subnetMask">The Submask IP Address</param>
    /// <param name="gateway">The gateway.</param>
    /// <remarks>Requires a reference to the System.Management namespace</remarks>
    public void SetIP(string ipAddress, string subnetMask, string gateway)
    {
        using (var networkConfigMng = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
        {
            using (var networkConfigs = networkConfigMng.GetInstances())
            {
                foreach (var managementObject in networkConfigs.Cast<ManagementObject>().Where(managementObject => (bool)managementObject["IPEnabled"]))
                {
                    using (var newIP = managementObject.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic"))
                    {
                        // Set new IP address and subnet if needed
                        if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress)) || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(subnetMask)))
                        {
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
                            {
                                newIP["IPAddress"] = new[] { ipAddress };
                            }

                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(subnetMask))
                            {
                                newIP["SubnetMask"] = new[] { subnetMask };
                            }

                            managementObject.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);
                        }

                        // Set mew gateway if needed
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(gateway))
                        {
                            using (var newGateway = managementObject.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways"))
                            {
                                newGateway["DefaultIPGateway"] = new[] { gateway };
                                newGateway["GatewayCostMetric"] = new[] { 1 };
                                managementObject.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", newGateway, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set's the DNS Server of the local machine
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nic">NIC address</param>
    /// <param name="dnsServers">Comma seperated list of DNS server addresses</param>
    /// <remarks>Requires a reference to the System.Management namespace</remarks>
    public void SetNameservers(string nic, string dnsServers)
    {
        using (var networkConfigMng = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
        {
            using (var networkConfigs = networkConfigMng.GetInstances())
            {
                foreach (var managementObject in networkConfigs.Cast<ManagementObject>().Where(objMO => (bool)objMO["IPEnabled"] && objMO["Caption"].Equals(nic)))
                {
                    using (var newDNS = managementObject.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder"))
                    {
                        newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = dnsServers.Split(',');
                        managementObject.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDNS, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the parameter 'nic' meant to contain in the setNameservers function?

Comment: its the name (description) of the network interface. you can enumerate them using NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().

Comment: Note: you must add a reference to System.Management to your project.

Answer (score 7):

I like the WMILinq solution. While not exactly the solution to your problem, find below a taste of it :

```
using (WmiContext context = new WmiContext(@"\\.")) {

  context.ManagementScope.Options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
  context.Log = Console.Out;

  var dnss = from nic in context.Source<Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration>()
          where nic.IPEnabled
          select nic;

  var ips = from s in dnss.SelectMany(dns => dns.DNSServerSearchOrder)
          select IPAddress.Parse(s);
}
```

http://www.codeplex.com/linq2wmi

Answer (score 6):

A far more clear solution is to use the command `netsh` to change the IP (or setting it back to DHCP)

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0
```

Where "Local Area Connection" is the name of the network adapter. You could find it in the windows Network Connections, sometimes it is simply named "Ethernet".

Here are two methods to set the IP and also to set the IP back to DHCP "Obtain an IP address automatically"

```
public bool SetIP(string networkInterfaceName, string ipAddress, string subnetMask, string gateway = null)
{
    var networkInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(nw => nw.Name == networkInterfaceName);
    var ipProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();
    var ipInfo = ipProperties.UnicastAddresses.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
    var currentIPaddress = ipInfo.Address.ToString();
    var currentSubnetMask = ipInfo.IPv4Mask.ToString();
    var isDHCPenabled = ipProperties.GetIPv4Properties().IsDhcpEnabled;

    if (!isDHCPenabled && currentIPaddress == ipAddress && currentSubnetMask == subnetMask)
        return true;    // no change necessary

    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", $"interface ip set address \"{networkInterfaceName}\" static {ipAddress} {subnetMask}" + (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gateway) ? "" : $"{gateway} 1")) { Verb = "runas" }
    };
    process.Start();
    var successful = process.ExitCode == 0;
    process.Dispose();
    return successful;
}

public bool SetDHCP(string networkInterfaceName)
{
    var networkInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(nw => nw.Name == networkInterfaceName);
    var ipProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();
    var isDHCPenabled = ipProperties.GetIPv4Properties().IsDhcpEnabled;

    if (isDHCPenabled)
        return true;    // no change necessary

    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", $"interface ip set address \"{networkInterfaceName}\" dhcp") { Verb = "runas" }
    };
    process.Start();
    var successful = process.ExitCode == 0;
    process.Dispose();
    return successful;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... this is just abuse netsh and external processes without any error handling to probably get what you were aiming for... doing it natively is a bit harder but worth the extra effort.

Comment: While I agree with @cb88 that this solution is not "pure C#", it's still solution! Not everybody needs to inspect Win32 debris (esp. clumsy WMI). If you can do the job with external command, why not? Finally, you need to SET IP, not expose your C# skills! :)

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more concise example that builds on top of the other answers here. I leveraged the code generation that is shipped with Visual Studio to remove most of the extra invocation code and replaced it with typed objects instead.

```
    using System;
    using System.Management;

    namespace Utils
    {
        class NetworkManagement
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Returns a list of all the network interface class names that are currently enabled in the system
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>list of nic names</returns>
            public static string[] GetAllNicDescriptions()
            {
                List<string> nics = new List<string>();

                using (var networkConfigMng = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
                {
                    using (var networkConfigs = networkConfigMng.GetInstances())
                    {
                        foreach (var config in networkConfigs.Cast<ManagementObject>()
                                                                           .Where(mo => (bool)mo["IPEnabled"])
                                                                           .Select(x=> new NetworkAdapterConfiguration(x)))
                        {
                            nics.Add(config.Description);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return nics.ToArray();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Set's the DNS Server of the local machine
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="nicDescription">The full description of the network interface class</param>
            /// <param name="dnsServers">Comma seperated list of DNS server addresses</param>
            /// <remarks>Requires a reference to the System.Management namespace</remarks>
            public static bool SetNameservers(string nicDescription, string[] dnsServers, bool restart = false)
            {
                using (ManagementClass networkConfigMng = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
                {
                    using (ManagementObjectCollection networkConfigs = networkConfigMng.GetInstances())
                    {
                        foreach (ManagementObject mboDNS in networkConfigs.Cast<ManagementObject>().Where(mo => (bool)mo["IPEnabled"] && (string)mo["Description"] == nicDescription))
                        {
                            // NAC class was generated by opening a developer console and entering:
                            // mgmtclassgen Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -p NetworkAdapterConfiguration.cs
                            // See: http://blog.opennetcf.com/2008/06/24/disableenable-network-connections-under-vista/

                            using (NetworkAdapterConfiguration config = new NetworkAdapterConfiguration(mboDNS))
                            {
                                if (config.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(dnsServers) == 0)
                                {
                                    RestartNetworkAdapter(nicDescription);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Restarts a given Network adapter
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="nicDescription">The full description of the network interface class</param>
            public static void RestartNetworkAdapter(string nicDescription)
            {
                using (ManagementClass networkConfigMng = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapter"))
                {
                    using (ManagementObjectCollection networkConfigs = networkConfigMng.GetInstances())
                    {
                        foreach (ManagementObject mboDNS in networkConfigs.Cast<ManagementObject>().Where(mo=> (string)mo["Description"] == nicDescription))
                        {
                            // NA class was generated by opening dev console and entering
                            // mgmtclassgen Win32_NetworkAdapter -p NetworkAdapter.cs
                            using (NetworkAdapter adapter = new NetworkAdapter(mboDNS))
                            {
                                adapter.Disable();
                                adapter.Enable();
                                Thread.Sleep(4000); // Wait a few secs until exiting, this will give the NIC enough time to re-connect
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Get's the DNS Server of the local machine
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="nicDescription">The full description of the network interface class</param>
            public static string[] GetNameservers(string nicDescription)
            {
                using (var networkConfigMng = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
                {
                    using (var networkConfigs = networkConfigMng.GetInstances())
                    {
                        foreach (var config  in networkConfigs.Cast<ManagementObject>()
                                                              .Where(mo => (bool)mo["IPEnabled"] && (string)mo["Description"] == nicDescription)
                                                              .Select( x => new NetworkAdapterConfiguration(x)))
                        {
                            return config.DNSServerSearchOrder;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Set's a new IP Address and it's Submask of the local machine
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="nicDescription">The full description of the network interface class</param>
            /// <param name="ipAddresses">The IP Address</param>
            /// <param name="subnetMask">The Submask IP Address</param>
            /// <param name="gateway">The gateway.</param>
            /// <remarks>Requires a reference to the System.Management namespace</remarks>
            public static void SetIP(string nicDescription, string[] ipAddresses, string subnetMask, string gateway)
            {
                using (var networkConfigMng = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
                {
                    using (var networkConfigs = networkConfigMng.GetInstances())
                    {
                        foreach (var config in networkConfigs.Cast<ManagementObject>()
                                                                       .Where(mo => (bool)mo["IPEnabled"] && (string)mo["Description"] == nicDescription)
                                                                       .Select( x=> new NetworkAdapterConfiguration(x)))
                        {
                            // Set the new IP and subnet masks if needed
                            config.EnableStatic(ipAddresses, Array.ConvertAll(ipAddresses, _ => subnetMask));

                            // Set mew gateway if needed
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(gateway))
                            {
                                config.SetGateways(new[] {gateway}, new ushort[] {1});
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Full source:
https://github.com/sverrirs/DnsHelper/blob/master/src/DnsHelperUI/NetworkManagement.cs

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers have quite broken code. The DNS method does not work at all. Here is code that I used to configure my NIC:

```
public static class NetworkConfigurator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Set's a new IP Address and it's Submask of the local machine
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ipAddress">The IP Address</param>
    /// <param name="subnetMask">The Submask IP Address</param>
    /// <param name="gateway">The gateway.</param>
    /// <param name="nicDescription"></param>
    /// <remarks>Requires a reference to the System.Management namespace</remarks>
    public static void SetIP(string nicDescription, string[] ipAddresses, string subnetMask, string gateway)
    {
        using (var networkConfigMng = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
        {
            using (var networkConfigs = networkConfigMng.GetInstances())
            {
                foreach (var managementObject in networkConfigs.Cast<ManagementObject>().Where(mo => (bool)mo["IPEnabled"] && (string)mo["Description"] == nicDescription))
                {
                    using (var newIP = managementObject.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic"))
                    {
                        // Set new IP address and subnet if needed
                        if (ipAddresses != null || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(subnetMask))
                        {
                            if (ipAddresses != null)
                            {
                                newIP["IPAddress"] = ipAddresses;
                            }

                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(subnetMask))
                            {
                                newIP["SubnetMask"] = Array.ConvertAll(ipAddresses, _ => subnetMask);
                            }

                            managementObject.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);
                        }

                        // Set mew gateway if needed
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(gateway))
                        {
                            using (var newGateway = managementObject.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways"))
                            {
                                newGateway["DefaultIPGateway"] = new[] { gateway };
                                newGateway["GatewayCostMetric"] = new[] { 1 };
                                managementObject.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", newGateway, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set's the DNS Server of the local machine
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nic">NIC address</param>
    /// <param name="dnsServers">Comma seperated list of DNS server addresses</param>
    /// <remarks>Requires a reference to the System.Management namespace</remarks>
    public static void SetNameservers(string nicDescription, string[] dnsServers)
    {
        using (var networkConfigMng = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
        {
            using (var networkConfigs = networkConfigMng.GetInstances())
            {
                foreach (var managementObject in networkConfigs.Cast<ManagementObject>().Where(mo => (bool)mo["IPEnabled"] && (string)mo["Description"] == nicDescription))
                {
                    using (var newDNS = managementObject.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder"))
                    {
                        newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = dnsServers;
                        managementObject.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDNS, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This maybe more clear:

```
static NetworkInterface GetNetworkInterface(string macAddress)
{
    foreach(NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        if (macAddress == ni.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString())
            return ni;
    }
    return null;
}
static ManagementObject GetNetworkInterfaceManagementObject(string macAddress)
{
    NetworkInterface ni = GetNetworkInterface(macAddress);
    if (ni == null)
        return null;
    ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ManagementObjectCollection moc = managementClass.GetInstances();
    foreach(ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        if (mo["settingID"].ToString() == ni.Id)
            return mo;
    }
    return null;
}
static bool SetupNIC(string macAddress, string ip, string subnet, string gateway, string dns)
{
    try
    {
        ManagementObject mo = GetNetworkInterfaceManagementObject(macAddress);

        //Set IP
        ManagementBaseObject mboIP = mo.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
        mboIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { ip };
        mboIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { subnet };
        mo.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", mboIP, null);

        //Set Gateway
        ManagementBaseObject mboGateway = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");
        mboGateway["DefaultIPGateway"] = new string[] { gateway };
        mboGateway["GatewayCostMetric"] = new int[] { 1 };
        mo.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", mboGateway, null);

        //Set DNS
        ManagementBaseObject mboDNS = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
        mboDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = new string[] { dns };
        mo.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", mboDNS, null);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is problem w DNS code - it's not set up.