# Automating IP address assignments with .Net (C#)?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, wmi

I need to automate IP Address assignments using .Net. Is there something already out there or can someone point me in the right direction. I know I can use WMI to do this, but some of the resources were for vbscript. I am hoping to use .Net

Update: I need to assign multiple static IPs to a single NIC

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me out: [How can you change Network settings (IP Address, DNS, WINS, Host Name) with code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code)