# Overriding default DNS servers in .NET ( C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dns

Id been searching and searching as  a friend told me  there is no way to change/modify the default DNS server settings using a WinForm ( in MS Windows) with some built in feature in .NET ( C#).

I did my homework ( despite being very new into programming) and found some links ( in Stackoverflow and google), but they were either abandoned projects or not C# .

c++
http://qa.lampcms.com/q124857/Can-temporarily-override-DNS-resolution-within-NET-application

error while "meshing"
http://qa.lampcms.com/tagged/dns+c#/

Appreciate any ideas .I m not seeking an exact answer, some guiding would be ok.

Comment: are you trying to subvert the hosts file?

Answer (score 2):

To change the DNS, you could follow the advice of the following SO question:

[How can you change Network settings (IP Address, DNS, WINS, Host Name) with code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code)

There is also a CodeProject article that shows you how to do it:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/oazswitchnetconfig.aspx