# WMI for quering active networks and associate connections

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, wmi

I need to change Network settings like described in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code). That works good so far. However I also need to know on what active network I make the changes.

(For a better understanding please open `Control Panel\Network and Internet\ Network and Sharing Center`. Unfortunately all picture hosting sites are blocked by my company so I can't post a screenshot.)

Any help on how I can query what connection is associated with what network with WMI (or other technology)?

**UPDATE:**

I need to query a remote machine.

Comment: Here http://networknerd.wordpress.com/2008/09/05/detect-physical-network-adapters-using-wmi/ and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx should help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `NetworkListManager` COM component, either with dynamic as shown below or using the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) which contains all the COM wrappers.

```
dynamic networkListManager = Activator.CreateInstance(
     Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("{DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}")));

var connections = networkListManager.GetNetworkConnections();
foreach (var connection in connections)
{
    var network = connection.GetNetwork();
    Console.WriteLine("Network Name: " + network.GetName());
    Console.WriteLine("Network Category " + 
        network.GetCategory()+ " (0 public / 1 private / 2 Authenticated AD)" );

}
```

PowerShell:

```
$networkType = [Type]::GetTypeFromCLSID('DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B')
$networkListManager = [Activator]::CreateInstance($networkType)

$netWorks = $networkListManager.GetNetworkConnections()

foreach ($network in $netWorks)
{
    $name = $network.GetName()
    $category = $network.GetCategory()

    write-host "Network Name: $name"
    write-host "Network Category: $category"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine so far. Just I forgot to mention that i need to query a remote machine.

Comment: That's make a big difference, you can do it with powershell and remoting.

Comment: This works well. Here is a documentation for the methods that can be used: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370750(v=vs.85).aspx