# Change network adapter advanced settings with c#

Tags: c#

I wonder if it possible to change my network adapter advanced settings with c#, i mean this settings:

[image]

what i want to change is the TCP and UDP Checksum offload to disable

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code

Comment: Under Windows 8 / Server 2k12, you could invoke the PowerShell cmdlet [`Disable-NetAdapterChecksumOffload`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130902.aspx).

Comment: I cannot find the option to change is the TCP and UDP Checksum offload to disable

Comment: There is no option to change the Checksum Offload through the CIM [`ManagementClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementclass.aspx). Your options seem to be the PS cmdlet (under Windows 8) or to edit the [registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff571012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly.
To disable both TCP and UDP offloading via PS, run: `Disable-NetAdapterChecksumOffload -InterfaceDescription "Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"`

Comment: Can i have an code example how to change the registry via c# ?