# Save and Load IP Config

Tags: config

I am evaluating possible ways to save and load static IP configuration (including TCP/IP settings > DNS, WINS etc.) over the network. I plan to use this on new PCs that will replace old ones with Windows 7.

So far, *ipconfig /all* for save and *netsh* for load are the best options using .bat file or .py script.

Are there any other ways of achieving the goal? Thanks!

Comment: what programming languages are you looking at, just the two mentioned?

Comment: open to any that is compatible with Win7

Comment: ok, what are you versed in?   Thats a pretty open ended answer about what language.  If someone was to give you C++ would you be able to read it, utilize it, and change it?   Anyways, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code

Comment: C, C++, Python. C# is not within reach yet. Since, I have to save the config, swap the PC and then load the config, I was considering saving the information to a file. Link shows example in C# for configuring... I could use APIs for querying current config the same way?