# Set up ip adresses with custom UI

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I would like to create a program with which the user can configure its tcp network settings like

- use DHCP or not
- if not, then set up ip-address, subnet, gateway, etc by hand.

Basically it should be what this dialog is doing:

[image]

Is this possible? I guess there could be some native win32 functions for this, which i could PInvoke.

Comment: have you done any research? I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/209779/238902) for instance. It seems to be answering your question?

Comment: are you asking how to create a custom UI (as the title suggests) or how to configure the tcp settings?

Comment: @Default to configure the tcp settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `System.Management` for this

```
 ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
 ManagementObjectCollection managementObjectCollection = objMC.GetInstances();
```

then you should be able to iterate the collection and change values that you need.