# Is there any way to programmatically change an IP address which would not require admin rights?

Tags: c++, .net, c#-4.0, ip

I require to be able to programmatically change an IP address without the need for admin rights on the end user PC.

The methods I have already attempted are: 
NETSH commands
AddIPAddress - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365801(v=vs.85).aspx

and .NET management class using the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class
[How can you change Network settings (IP Address, DNS, WINS, Host Name) with code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code)

It just seems there is no way at runtime to accomplish this, I have read about using a batch file at start up to create the necessary permissions or enabling UAC but both of these are not possible for the end user.

Cheers :)

Comment: I would certainly *hope* there isn't a way to do this.  If there was, it would be potentially serious security risk.

Comment: You can't do that, and *shouldn't be able* to do that, without administrator right.

Comment: This is exactly what I think, it's quite a silly requirement really. I thought I would ask the world if there may be any extremely low level way to achieve this.

Comment: Just imagine what a virus could do if it was able to change your IP Address (well it could if it runs under the admin account)...

Comment: Assume it was possible; it would be a elevation of privilege bug and patched in next month's security update. (Unless you target just XP of course)

Comment: Why are you looking to change IP address? Even if it was possible it smells of a bad way of doing things - there must be a more reliable way to accomplish your business goals I would have thought.

Comment: Do you know any other way to change IP address of system?
I have a software in php, in which we provide all the netwrok settings(IP address, gatway etc) in GUI.
I just want to change these settings to system.