# Setting a specific NIC with static IP Address in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I'm trying to set a specific NIC with a static IP Address. I was referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code) SO post (answered by Marc) which show's how to do so except it will set all NIC's which are Enabled. I'm trying to only set a specific one. This is what I thought you'd do it but it doesn't work and I'm wording if anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
foreach (var managementObject in networkConfigs.Cast<ManagementObject>().Where(managementObject => (bool)managementObject["Caption"].ToString().Contains("Local Area Connection 2")))
    {
    .. the rest of the code is the same...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `(bool)managementObject["Caption"].ToString()` returns the actual name of the adapter(i.e. Intel(R) Gigabit Network Connection) not the network name (i.e. Local Area Connection 2).