# Setting Static IP Address VB.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, networking

I am writing a script for setting static ip to computers. it reads a file that has mac addr - ip addr pair. based on the computers mac address it gets its ip address from the file. I have problem setting this up. I have never done any kind of .net programming. I wrote a bashscript for linux side which works, but for windows I don't have any experience. I wrote the program in vb.net. Until now the program can get the data from the file, now I have to set static ip based on the mac address and also hostname. there were several different posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125275/setting-a-specific-nic-with-static-ip-address-in-c-sharp), [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6975/SwitchNetConfig-Laptop-users-quickly-switch-networ), but they were all in c# ,and have problem converting them to VB.Net. It would be great if someone could provide a pointer on how to Set Static IP address for a specific NIC on local computer.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Management


Module Module1

Const FAILURE = 1
Const SUCCESS = 0
Dim phyAddr As String = getMAC()


Sub Main()

    Dim arguments(3) As String
    Dim fileName As String = ""


    If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs.Count = 3 Then

        arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs
        fileName = arguments(2)

    Else

        Console.WriteLine("Wrong Syntax!")
        help()
        Console.Read()
        close(FAILURE)

    End If

    If validName(fileName) Then

        If fileExists(fileName) Then

            'search file for ip 
            Dim confData As String = searchFile(phyAddr, fileName)

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(confData) Then

                Dim netConf() As String = splitLine(confData)

                Dim hostName As String = netConf(1)
                Dim ipAddr As String = netConf(2)
                Dim netMask As String = netConf(3)
                Dim gateway As String = netConf(4)
                Dim dns1 As String = netConf(5)
                Dim dns2 As String = netConf(6)




            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find MAC {0} in file {1}", phyAddr, fileName)
                Console.Read()
                close(FAILURE)
            End If


        Else

            Console.WriteLine("File {0} doesn't exist", fileName)
            Console.WriteLine("Please provide an absolute path to file")
            Console.Read()
            close(FAILURE)
        End If

    Else
        Console.WriteLine("File name {0} not recognized", fileName)
        Console.Read()
        close(FAILURE)
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub help()
    Console.WriteLine("Please call program as: ")
    Console.WriteLine("networkconfiguration -f datafile")
End Sub

Private Sub close(exitCode As Integer)
    Environment.Exit(exitCode)
End Sub

Private Function validName(name As String) As Boolean
    Static fileNameExpression As New Regex("^[\\:_a-zA-Z0-9.]+")
    Return fileNameExpression.IsMatch(name)
End Function

Private Function fileExists(name As String) As Boolean
    Return My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(name)

End Function

Private Function getMAC() As String

    Dim nic As NetworkInterface
    Dim result As String = String.Empty

    For Each nic In NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        If nic.Name.Contains("Ethernet0") Then
            result = nic.GetPhysicalAddress.ToString
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return result
End Function


Private Function searchFile(keyword As String, fileName As String) As String

    'store result
    Dim result As String = String.Empty

    'search for keyword in returned data
    Using reader As New StreamReader(fileName)
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
            If line.Contains(keyword) Then
                result = line
                Exit While
            End If
        End While
    End Using

    Return result

End Function

Private Function splitLine(line As String) As String()
    Dim separator As Char = ";"
    Return line.Split(separator)
End Function


Private Function setupNetwork(ipAddr As String, netmask As String, gateway As String, dns1 As String, dns2 As String) As Boolean

    Dim mc As New ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
    Dim moc As New ManagementObjectCollection
    Dim mo As ManagementObject

    moc = mc.GetInstances()
    For Each mo In moc
        'make sure this is ipenabled device
        'not something like memory card or VMWare

    Next






End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok solved it. I will just post my answer here so others might benefit.

```
' set the network configuration of a computer
Function setupNetwork(phyAddr As String, ipAddr As String, netmask As String, gateway As String, dns1 As String, dns2 As String) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False

    ' concatenate two dns addresses into one
    Dim dnsSearchOrder As String = dns1 + "," + dns2

    Dim objMC As ManagementClass = New ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
    Dim objMOC As ManagementObjectCollection = objMC.GetInstances()

    For Each objMO As ManagementObject In objMOC

        If (CBool(objMO("IPEnabled"))) Then

            ' remove colons from mac address so that it could match the
            ' provided mac address
            Dim origMAC As String = objMO("MacAddress").ToString()
            Dim pattern As String = ":"
            Dim replacement As String = ""
            Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
            ' the mac address with colons removed from it
            Dim repMAC As String = rgx.Replace(origMAC, replacement)

            If (String.Equals(phyAddr, repMAC)) Then
                Try
                    Dim objNewIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
                    Dim objNewGate As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
                    Dim objNewDNS As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
                    Dim objSetIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing

                    objNewIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic")
                    objNewGate = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways")
                    objNewDNS = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder")

                    'set defaultgateway
                    objNewGate("DefaultIPGateway") = New String() {gateway}
                    objNewGate("GatewayCostMetric") = New Integer() {1}

                    'set ipaddress and subnetmask
                    objNewIP("IPAddress") = New String() {ipAddr}
                    objNewIP("SubnetMask") = New String() {netmask}
                    objNewDNS("DNSServerSearchOrder") = dnsSearchOrder.Split(",")

                    objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", objNewIP, Nothing)
                    objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", objNewGate, Nothing)
                    objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", objNewDNS, Nothing)

                    result = True
                    Exit For

                Catch ex As Exception
                    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't Set IP Address!")
                    Console.Read()
                    close(FAILURE)

                End Try

            End If

        End If
    Next



    Return result

End Function

'set computers host name
Private Function setHostname(hostname As String) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False

    Dim path As New ManagementPath

    path.Server = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
    path.NamespacePath = "root\CIMV2"
    path.RelativePath = "Win32_Computersystem.Name='" & path.Server & "'"

    Dim objMO As New ManagementObject(path)
    Dim params() As Object = {hostname}
    objMO.InvokeMethod("Rename", params)
    result = True

    Return result
End Function
```