# I cant change registry value

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

I am trying to write an application to be able to change  a few registry values.Such as Dns Server,Defalut Gateway .I am using this code below for doing this

```
 RegistryKey openSubKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path, true);
            if (openSubKey != null)
            {

                //HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{F7DFBC05-B946-4C27-A58B-13BFB3FCC04E}


                    openSubKey.SetValue("IPAddress", "192.168.2.132");
                    openSubKey.SetValue("SubnetMask", "255.255.255.0");
                    openSubKey.SetValue("DefaultGateway", "192.168.2.2");
                    openSubKey.SetValue("NameServer", ""192.168.2.132,192.168.2.132"");
```

.Actually code works .I can see the new values in th registry as you can see

[image]

However when I check network connections I have realized that nothing changed
but NameServer.What am I doing wrong here.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change your IP address when it's configured to pick up settings from DHCP? I seriously doubt it. I'm not sure that changing the registry is the correct way to set these values.

Comment: You should use a documented API for this, such as WMI

Comment: You haven't uttered the Simsalabim incantation that forces the TCP stack to read the registry again.  Or used the correct registry key.  Yes, use WMI instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is instead of direct registry manipulation, use WMI. See this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code) or this [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5697/Configuring-TCP-IP-Settings-using-WMI-and-C) on using WMI to update the Network Configuration.

Mostly you will have to work with Win32_[NetworkAdapterConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI object.