# Change IP address / DHCP settings for Interface

Tags: c#, mono

System.Management seems not to be implemented.
Is there any way or will I have to wrap the system calls myself?

Cheers

Comment: Hmm maybe this post helps ya http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code

Comment: This seems to use System.Management which AFAIK is .NET only. I need this to run under mono on linux

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/ it does not map to linux no hmm :(

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: Debian. Currently Wheezy with the Jessie Kernel. Will have to move to Jessie when its stable.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no way to properly do this out of the box with Mono.

My suggestion (and what I am attempting right now, also) is to simply parse /etc/network/interfaces and do it that way.

A good start would be this Awk script that parses Interfaces https://joekuan.wordpress.com/2009/11/01/awk-scripts-for-reading-and-editing-ubuntu-etcnetworkinterfaces-file-part-22/

Good luck!