# Machine IP reset does nothing

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a tool for work that needs to reset the PC IP address to a specific IP and subnet mask.

I've used the code below to try to change the IP (taken from this page: [How can you change Network settings (IP Address, DNS, WINS, Host Name) with code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code)).

The problem is, this code doesn't do anything. The IP address of my computer's local connection doesn't change - it's still being automatically set via DHCP.

Help?

```
public void SetIP(string ip_address, string subnet_mask)
    {

        ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
        {
            if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
            {
                try
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject setIP;
                    ManagementBaseObject newIP =
                        objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");

                    newIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { ip_address };
                    newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { subnet_mask };

                    setIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) What is returned as setIP result? 2) Did you try to run this under administrator privileges?

Comment: How do I get setIP into a readable result?

Comment: Okay, so running as an administrator makes it work, but I need to be able to reset the IP even when not running as an admin. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you try this, you should obtain the reason for failure:

```
MessageBox.Show("ReturnValue : " + setIP["ReturnValue"].ToString());
```

Tried by OP, with this result:

> This gives me 2147749891 as a return value. Does that mean anything to you?

As Yury suggested make sure you have admin privileges and UAC is not stopping you. A quick search of that error resulted with:

> WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED 2147749891 (0x80041003) Current user does not have permission to perform the action

Comment: This gives me 2147749891 as a return value. Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: As Yury suggested make sure you have admin privileges and UAC is not stopping you. A quick search of that error resulted with..

WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED

2147749891 (0x80041003) Current user does not have permission to perform the action

Answer (score 0):

So, as we figured out so far, the main reason is lack of privileges. As MSDN says about ManagementObject.InvokeMethod(), you need to be in fully-trusted execution scope:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssk42c11(v=vs.110).aspx

> **Remarks**
>   **.NET Framework Security**
>   Full trust for the immediate caller. This member cannot be used by
>   partially trusted code.

So indeed you have to run this snippet under admin or analogous account.