# What is Get-NetIPInterface in C# .NET

Tags: c#, powershell

Does anybody know what is Powershell commands: "`Get-NetIPInterface`" and "`Set-NetIPInterface`" in C# .NET? I want to write a simple application to do these commands jobs.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By using WMI. There are posts about this already. Check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code) out.