# how to ADD IP address in Windows 10 using C#

Tags: c#, powershell-3.0

I want to add multiple IP addresses in my Ethernet port.
I tried below both way

1. using **Management Class**

   ```
   public void setIP()
       {
           string myDesc = "Realtek USB GbE Family Controller";
           string gateway = "10.210.255.1";
           string subnetMask = "255.255.255.0";
           string address = "10.210.255.102";

           var adapterConfig = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
           var networkCollection = adapterConfig.GetInstances();

           foreach (ManagementObject adapter in networkCollection)
           {
               string description = adapter["Description"] as string;
               if (string.Compare(description,
                   myDesc, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       // Set DefaultGateway
                       var newGateway = adapter.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");
                       newGateway["DefaultIPGateway"] = new string[] { gateway };
                       newGateway["GatewayCostMetric"] = new int[] { 1 };

                       // Set IPAddress and Subnet Mask
                       var newAddress = adapter.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
                       newAddress["IPAddress"] = new string[] { address };
                       newAddress["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { subnetMask };

                       adapter.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newAddress, null);
                       adapter.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", newGateway, null);

                       Console.WriteLine("Updated to static IP address!");
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("Unable to Set IP : " + ex.Message);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   ```
2. Using **PowerShellSCript in C#**

   ```
   private string RunScript()
       {

                 string scriptText = "$iplist = \"10.210.255.102\"" + "," + " \"10.210.255.103\"" + "\nforeach ($ip in $iplist)" +"\n{" +" \nNew-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias \"Ethernet\" -IPAddress $ip -PrefixLength 24" +"\n}";

           // create Powershell runspace

           Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

           // open it

           runspace.Open();

           // create a pipeline and feed it the script text

           Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
           pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

           // add an extra command to transform the script
           // output objects into nicely formatted strings

           // remove this line to get the actual objects
           // that the script returns. For example, the script

           // "Get-Process" returns a collection
           // of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.

           pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

           // execute the script

           var results = pipeline.Invoke();

           // close the runspace

           runspace.Close();

           // convert the script result into a single string

           StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           foreach (PSObject obj in results)
           {
               stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
           }

           return stringBuilder.ToString();
       }
   ```

Both are not working, my code working properly it's not going inside catch,
but not able to add IP,
even I can add IP using running power script file from Windows PowerShell, but the same script is not working inside C#,

all I am trying to add a number of IP address in Single Ethernet card

Note: yes I have Admin rights, I already perform this manually and using PowerShell tool power script.
one more thing,
every time i have to right-click window PowerShell and run as administrator to run my scrip

Comment: What is returned by your two calls to `adapter.InvokeMethod()`?  You don't check the result.  Just because no exception is thrown doesn't mean the invoked method succeeded.

Comment: Also, your question is essentially "Why does this first snippet execute without errors but not produce the expected result?" _and_ "Why does this second script work when invoked directly from PowerShell but not C#?"  That's good that you tried multiple approaches to solve your problem, but asking about two completely different attempts that are each failing in a different way I think makes this question too broad.  Unless you're just looking for _any_ way to set static IPs, in which case I'd be surprised if that hasn't been asked before ([similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/209779/150605)).

Comment: @BACON I already tried a solution which you are suggesting, yes ultimately I want to add multiple static IP, but something is wrong, some setting, registry I don't know, thats why I posted multiple ways just to figure out what exactly I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved, Run Exe As a administratoror, Run Visual studio as a Administrator .

I go further and added multiple IP addresses, and Subnet makst in Single Ethernet card

```
var newAddress = adapter.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
                        newAddress["IPAddress"] = new string[] { address, address1 };
                        newAddress["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { subnetMask,subnetMask };

                        var cal1 = adapter.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newAddress, null);
```

Comment: The question stated you were already running as an administrator, so I don't understand how this is the solution.  Was your code running with an administrator-but-not-elevated security token?  Also, had you checked the return values of the `adapter.InvokeMethod()` calls presumably they would have returned [`WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-error-constants#WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED) or [`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-#ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) to indicate a rights issue.

Comment: @BACON yes I checked return value it doesn't return any Error,
my user has administrator rights but I don't know why its require to start the application as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

for the Powershell solution, it can be a real pain to get a script working in c#. Usually I prefer using the Powershell class, you can try this approach:

Using Scripts:

```cs
var Ps = PowerShell.Create();
//you can create the variable like this:
Ps.AddCommand("Set-Variable").AddParameter("Name", "tsinfo").AddParameter("Value", result);
Ps.Invoke();
//Execute your script
Ps.Commands.Clear();
Ps.AddScript("foreach ($ip in $iplist)" +"\n{" +" \nNew-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias \"Ethernet\" -IPAddress $ip -PrefixLength 24" +"\n}");
Ps.Invoke();
```

Or using Commands:

```cs
var iplist = new List<string> { "10.210.255.102", "10.210.255.103"};
foreach(var ip in iplist){
    Ps.Commands.Clear();
    Ps.AddCommand("New-NetIPAddress").AddParameter("InterfaceAlias", "Ethernet").AddParameter("IPAddress", ip).AddParameter("PrefixLength", 24);
    Ps.Invoke();
}
```

Hope it'll help

Comment: Same as what My code does, no Error but simply IP not added.
I run a solution as an administrator and the above question code is working now !!