# Passing values from Form text-box to .bat, to set computer's IP

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file

I have the following .bat file (called ip-set):

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static %ip %sub %def
pause
exit
```

And the following C# (which passes arguments to the .bat and executes it):

```
proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = String.Format(@"C:\test\WindowsFormsApplication1\setup");
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "ip-set";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
proc.Start();
```

I keep getting the error: "Invalid address parameter (sub). It should be a valid IPv4 address."

I don't know what's wrong / missing.

Comment: Where are you setting `%ip` and the rest?  The parameters should be `%1`, `%2`, and `%3`

Comment: Print the formatted arguments to ensure it is correct. BTW I would rather do a system call.

Comment: Variables in batch are called with `%variable%`, not `%variable` (note the percent signs on both sides of the variable name).

Comment: Batch files do not have named arguments like other scripting languages if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: [How can you change Network settings (IP Address, DNS, WINS, Host Name)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/209779/7444103)